# Ломается ссылка при создании кнопки, не видит фигурные скобки, KeyError at

Tags: python, django

**Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с весьма неприятной проблемой.**
Суть в том, что при формировании кнопки либо у меня ломается ссылка, выстраивая вместо конкретного урла str:username/orders/int:id/detail, совсем странный адрес. И глядя на этот странный адрес, складывается ощущение, что {% %} просто игнорируются.

Я использую кастомные фильтры для вывода информации в шаблоне, и необходимо присваивать ссылке-кнопке определённый адрес, который бы вёл к подробностям заказа.

Вот весь код.

**Фрагмент кода из шаблона "Заказы в профиле"**

```
{% if orders|check_orders_exist_by:"new" %}
        <div class="collapse" id="activeOrders">
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Номер</th>
                        <th scope="col">Количество книг</th>
                        <th scope="col">Книги</th>
                        <th scope="col">Стоимость</th>
                        <th scope="col"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for order in orders|sort_orders_by:"new" %}
                    {{ order|output_orders_by_status:"new" }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
{% endif %}
```

**templatetag - output_orders.py** Проблема в этом файле. Обратите внимание на TABLE_CONTENT, пункт с формированием ссылки. Что нужно вставить в href ?

```
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

from main.models import Order

register = template.Library()

TABLE_CONTENT = '''
                <tr>
                    <td width="5%">{num}</td>
                    <td width="5%">{total_books}</td>
                    <td width="10%">
                        <ul>
                            {books}
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td width="5%">{price}</td>
                    p_order_detail
                    <td width="10%"><a href="{% url 'profile_order_detail' username=request.user.username id=order.id %}" 
                    class='btn btn-sm btn-success' role='button'>Подробнее</td>
                </tr>
                '''


def get_book_information(order):
    table_content_books = ''
    cart_books = order.cart.related_books.all()
    for item in cart_books:
        table_content_books += f'<li>{item.book.title} x {item.quantity}</li>'
    return table_content_books


def form_content(order):
    table_content = ''
    num = order.id
    price = order.cart.final_price
    total_books = order.cart.total_books
    books = get_book_information(order)

    table_content = TABLE_CONTENT.format(
        num=num, price=price, total_books=total_books, books=books)

    return table_content


@ register.filter
def output_orders_by_status(order, status):
    if order.status == status:
        return mark_safe(form_content(order))
    else:
        return None


@ register.filter
def sort_orders_by(orders, status):
    sorted_orders = orders.filter(status=status)
    return sorted_orders


@ register.filter
def check_orders_exist_by(orders, status):
    if orders.filter(status=status).exists():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

**views.py**

```
class ProfileOrderDetailView(CartMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        order = Order.objects.get(id=kwargs.get('id'))
        context = {
            'order': order,
            'cart': self.cart
        }
        return render(request, 'main/profile_orders_detail.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('<str:username>/orders/<int:id>/detail', ProfileOrderDetailView.as_view(), name='profile_order_detail'),
```

Вот собственно скриншот сайта. Зелёная кнопка - это то, что создаётся через шаблонный фильтр django и к нему надо приписать ссылку.

[image: Са]

Comment: Почему пробел между `@` и `register.filter`?

Comment: Попробуйте через `format` подсунуть `reverse` урла?

Comment: @Dima В коде у меня всё равно. Это опечатка уже здесь. Насчёт reverse сейчас попробую сделать.

Comment: @Dima да, reverse помог. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `TABLE_CONTENT` заменить `{% url 'profile_order_detail' username=request.user.username id=order.id %}` на `{profile_order_detail}` и в коде при обращении к этой строке в `format` подставлять `reverse`. Например,

```
table_content = TABLE_CONTENT.format(
    ...,
    profile_order_detail=reverse("profile_order_detail", args=(request.user.username, order.id))
)
```